# Rails: One to Many how to access data in the Many from the One

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many

Hi I'm quite new to Rails so sorry if this is dumb. I've been searching for hours. Not even sure what to ask. Thanks so much for any help.

I'm trying to have a table with Codes and Descriptions. Then another Main table with the codes in it. Join these two tables so I can sort by the codes and pull the description. I can't seem to figure out the code to pull the description.

This is the Code and Description migration

```
create_table :sniffs do |t|
  t.string "sniff_desc", :limit => 5
  t.timestamps
end
```

This is Main table migration

```
create_table :lenders do |t|
  t.integer "sniff_id"
  t.timestamps
end    

add_index("lenders", "sniff_id")
```

These are the models

```
class Lender < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sniffs
  scope :ranked, order("lenders.sniff_id ASC")
end

class Sniff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lenders
end
```

The sniffs table is

```
id  sniff_desc
 1  Great
 2  OK
 3  Bad
```

lenders table is

```
id  sniff_id
 1  2
 2  2
 3  3
```

This is what I can't figure out? How for a specific lender instance do I get a sniff_desc. For example, I'm on lender.id(2) and I want to get it's sniff_desc "OK".

So if I'm rails console

```
    lender = Lender.find(2)
    lender.sniffs
```

I get

```
=> nil
```

I thought I'd get the second record in sniffs. If I type this

```
Sniff.find(lender.sniff_id).sniff_desc
```

I get the right answer

```
=> "OK"
```

but that code seems to defeat the whole purpose of doing a one to many relationship.

Am I not understanding one-to-many correct? Or what do I do to fix this?

Thanks so much for any help. I think this question is too simple so I couldn't find anyone else asking it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right. The only problem is that `belongs_to` uses singulars, not plurals.

You have to change:

```
belongs_to :sniffs
```

To:

```
belongs_to :sniff
```

With this you should be able to do:

```
lender = Lender.find(2)
lender.sniff.sniff_desc #=> "OK"
```

Comment: Awww thank you sooo much Mischa!!! Yes, it works. I won't make that mistake again. Thank you.